# Passing properties from native to React Native when using Wix React Native Navigation (RNN)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Passing properties from native to React Native is described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios#passing-properties-from-native-to-react-native). Here's a summary:

```c
NSArray *imageList = @[@"http://foo.com/bar1.png",
                       @"http://foo.com/bar2.png"];

NSDictionary *props = @{@"images" : imageList};

RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                 moduleName:@"ImageBrowserApp"
                                          initialProperties:props];
```

However, when using [Wix React Native Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), there is no `rootView`. According to the docs, this is what a minimal RNN setup looks like on iOS:

```c
 #import "AppDelegate.h"

 #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
 #import <React/RCTRootView.h>
 #import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

 @implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
     [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

     return YES;
 }

 @end
```

How do we go about passing props from native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [create a native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#native-module-setup) for that. The module exposes public methods which return results by [resolving a promise](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#promises).

Answer (score 0):

As I passing property from React Native to native iOS you need to check for native iOS to React Native property passing. Here is my code

In iOS

**Appdelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@import Firebase;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeModule>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

**Appdelegate.m**

```
#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)propertyName)
{
    //Here you get your property value
    var property = propertyName;
    RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", areaId);
}
```

In React Native

**MyComponent.js**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

var AppDelegate = NativeModules.AppDelegate;
AppDelegate.addEvent(value);
```